Measurement of low currents (0.2 nA) and bipolar DC voltage in a PCB
Good afternoon! I have several questions regarding how to measure low currents down to 0.2 nA and bipolar DC voltage in the configuration of devices that I am developing.
Let me explain the situation. I am a beginner PCB designer, and I am currently developing a switch that should provide the routing of signals from an external voltage source module and another connected measurement module to a CMOS chip installed in the switch.
The test involves measuring the logic threshold level of the chip, which requires measuring the current and voltage at a selected pin of the chip.
The technical requirements specify the following conditions for the measurement instruments:

I am also providing a general representation of the connection structure to the chip pin.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Accordingly, my question is: what circuit design solutions can be used here to measure currents with an accuracy of up to 0.2 nA within the specified range, while operating with a maximum bipolar power supply voltage of ±20 V?
Additionally, could you please advise on any other nuances when measuring such low currents that I need to take into account? I am already considering the leakage currents in the relays being used

Measuring currents below a few hundred nanoamps or so is absolutely not a beginner task. Trust me, this is a way more complicated and difficult task than you think.
